# How to drive +-10V Gate-Source N-MOSFET from 30 V

Tags: mosfet

I have N-MOSFET with maximum +-10V Gate-Source voltage and I need to drive it with 30V signal. Is voltage divider way to go?

Comment: It depends. How often do you want to switch, how fast do you need to switch, what other supplies are available? But probably not.

Comment: How about R+Zener?

Comment: It will be switching magnetic gripper so quite seldom, and no other supplies are available.

Comment: how well controlled must the gate be? are 1MegOhm voltage dividers, which with 1,000pF (1nF) of Cgate will provide 0.001 second of switching, a safe time? or must you switch in 10 nanoseconds?